# what ical event parameter does google use for title

Tags: asp.net, google-calendar-api, icalendar

I am using ical.net for a calendar subscription. [Here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Ical.Net/2.2.34) I have it up and working correctly EXCEPT when I use a google calendar to subscribe, all events are listed as (no title). I found that Apple Calendar and Outlook use the calendar event's Summary for their event title or name, but am unsure what Google uses or if there is a workaround or known issue?

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
PRODID:-//ddaysoftware.com//NONSGML DDay.iCal 1.0//EN
BEGIN:VEVENT
DESCRIPTION:
DTEND:20170415T143000
DTSTAMP:20170504T235859Z
DTSTART:20170415T140000
LOCATION:123 Main St\, Lansing MI 48910
SEQUENCE:0
SUMMARY:Jane Doe - unconfirmed
UID:755dce86-be8d-4bd7-a93f-a108ec4d08b4
BEGIN:VALARM
ACTION:Display
SUMMARY:Upcoming appointment: Jane Doe - unconfirmed
TRIGGER:-PT1H
END:VALARM
END:VEVENT
BEGIN:VEVENT
DESCRIPTION:
DTEND:20170502T120000
DTSTAMP:20170504T235859Z
DTSTART:20170502T113000
LOCATION:123 Main St\, Lansing MI 48910
SEQUENCE:0
SUMMARY:Jane Doe - unconfirmed
UID:7eadb27e-0f07-4b94-aaf1-5b2aa23c5416
BEGIN:VALARM
ACTION:Display
SUMMARY:Upcoming appointment: Jane Doe - unconfirmed
TRIGGER:-PT1H
END:VALARM
END:VEVENT
BEGIN:VEVENT
DESCRIPTION:
DTEND:20170423T133000
DTSTAMP:20170504T235859Z
DTSTART:20170423T123000
LOCATION:564 side st\, Lansing MI 48911
SEQUENCE:0
SUMMARY:John Doe - unconfirmed
UID:a0f12654-7a77-491f-bfeb-7c80f7bd6b11
BEGIN:VALARM
ACTION:Display
SUMMARY:Upcoming appointment: John Doe - unconfirmed
TRIGGER:-PT1H
END:VALARM
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

Comment: Google for sure also makes use of the SUMMARY property so the issue is quite likely to be found in some formatting issue on your side. You should provide a sample subscription (full ical stream) in your question.